# Can I upload image from web (save a copy) using paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I was wondering if I have web address of a photo, can I save a copy of it on my website using paperclip? If so how?

Comment: Did someone answered your question ?

Comment: Thanks for answering. its just took me sometime to try it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it's actually pretty easy. There's the code from my user model using an avatar :

```
  #a part of your model
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :thumb => "50x50"  }, :storage => :s3,
                      :path => "/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                      :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/s3.yml")

  attr_accessor :avatar_url

  before_validation :download_remote_file, :if => :avatar_url_provided?

  def avatar_url_provided?
    !self.avatar_url.blank?
  end

  def download_remote_file
    self.avatar = do_download_remote_file
  end

  def do_download_remote_file
    io = open(URI.parse(avatar_url))
            def 
                io.original_filename
                base_uri.path.split('/').last
            end
    io.original_filename.blank? ? nil : io
        rescue  Exception => exc
        logger.debug "ERROR WHEN DOWNLOADING REMOTE AVATAR FOR USER #{self.id} AND REMOTE URL #{self.avatar_url} - ERROR IS #{exc.message}"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

of course you can do it